# how to groovy clousure like java 8?

Tags: groovy, java-8

In java 8 I've the next code:

```
control.focusedProperty().addListener(

                (observableValue, t, t1) -> {

                    //some code
        });
```

how can I have the same with groovy?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried

```
control.focusedProperty().addListener( { observableValue, t, t1 ->
    //some code
} ) ;
```

With Groovy 2.3.0 and the SAM types, I believe that should work...